# Device Tree configuration for I2S sound (MAX98357A)?

Tags: audio, device-tree

What needs to be done to run an I2S DAC/Amplifier board based on MAX98357A ([datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf)) that appears to be a clone of [this well-documented Adafruit product](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp) with the corresponding Device Tree overlay?

Following the Adafruit instructions to modify `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac
dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
#dtparam=audio=on
```

and creating the recommended `/etc/asound.conf`, **I have audio** (on left, right seems to be shut down via GPIO4).
However, [the I2S interface in combination with that IC causes pops and crackle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74456/i2s-dac-device-support-kernel-drivers-and-noise-pop-crackle-on-playbac) and I would like to use the shutdown pin of the chip/board.

The Device Tree Overlay specifically for this chip supports this

- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/max98357a-overlay.dts (not sure if this is the right branch)
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/max98357a.txt

But this does not work (**no audio**, and error, see below):

```
dtoverlay=max98357a
dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
#dtparam=audio=on
```

No audio device found

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ speaker-test -c2

speaker-test 1.1.8

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

Also:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
speakerbonnet
dmixer
softvol
default
```

There does not appear to be an error in `dmesg`.
The device tree overlay "binary" is present in:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /boot/overlays/max98357a.dtbo
/boot/overlays/max98357a.dtbo
```

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README#L1575

```
Name:   max98357a
Info:   Configures the Maxim MAX98357A I2S DAC
Load:   dtoverlay=max98357a,<param>=<val>
Params: no-sdmode               Driver does not manage the state of the DAC's
                                SD_MODE pin (i.e. chip is always on).
        sdmode-pin              integer, GPIO pin connected to the SD_MODE input
                                of the DAC (default GPIO4 if parameter omitted).
```

I'm assuming this would default to using SD with GPIO4!?

For comparison, the overlay for hifiberry-dac is

- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/hifiberry-dac-overlay.dts

Additional docs:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/simple-scu-card.txt
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/sound/simple-card.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver module (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/sound/soc/codecs/max98357a.c) is currently not configured for building by default and as such is not present in Raspberry Pi OS (ex. Raspbian) at the moment.